# Why use sleep after chmod in a Dockerfile

Tags: azure, docker, dockerfile, azure-web-app-service

The Azure documentation gives instructions for how to [enable SSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#enable-ssh) in a custom container. They suggest to add these commands in my Dockerfile:

```
# Install OpenSSH and set the password for root to "Docker!". In this example, "apk add" is the install instruction for an Alpine Linux-based image.
RUN apk add openssh \
     && echo "root:Docker!" | chpasswd 

# Copy the sshd_config file to the /etc/ssh/ directory
COPY sshd_config /etc/ssh/

# Copy and configure the ssh_setup file
RUN mkdir -p /tmp
COPY ssh_setup.sh /tmp
RUN chmod +x /tmp/ssh_setup.sh \
    && (sleep 1;/tmp/ssh_setup.sh 2>&1 > /dev/null)

# Open port 2222 for SSH access
EXPOSE 80 2222
```

Why is there a `sleep 1` after the `chmod +x` command? I know it's not harmful, but I'd really like to understand why it's there.

Comment: How is this related to programming? --- Why not ask azure support?

Comment: @Turing85 That would be another option. I'm asking here because I suspect that there may be something I don't know about bash/shell scripting that could explain the `sleep` command. However, maybe this is something specific to Azure or maybe it's completely unnecessary (i.e. a non-optimal example). I just don't know which it is so I started here.

Comment: There is nothing about the shell that calls for a sleep there.

Comment: It was added as part of this issue, but there's no explanation of why. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/81652. If you can find a way to contact Ryan Hill, you might ask him.

Comment: Great find @HansKilian! I opened an issue against the docs here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/103306

Answer (score -1):

The sleep 1 command is there to pause the script for 1 second before continuing. It is often used as a way to give the system time to complete a task or stabilize before the script continues.

In this case, the chmod +x command is used to make the ssh_setup.sh script executable. It is likely that the sleep 1 command is included to give the system time to complete this task before the script is run.

Keep in mind that this is just a suggestion and the use of the sleep 1 command may not be necessary in all cases. It is included as a way to potentially avoid any issues that may arise if the script continues before the system has had a chance to fully process the previous command.

Comment: Given the fact that `chmod` literally only sets some bits and does not run asynchronously, I see nothing that justifies the `sleep` to "give the system time".

Comment: Is this a ChatGPT answer? It feels like it.

Comment: Care to elaborate Richard? Your answer explains the general function of sleep but doesn't really answer the question.